# How to make a github branch in desktop for a certain minecraft version

Tags: git, github, minecraft, bukkit

Hi I have a GitHub repository and I am using GitHub desktop. I have this repo for my minecraft spigot plugin, the spigot/minecraft version is 1.9.4 and I run a 1.9.4 spigot server to test the plugin. Now I want to create a branch where the plugin is with the minecraft/spigot 1.10 api so people who have a 1.10 server can use my plugin, but I want to develop onto the 1.9.4 branch. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First send your current version on git like previous version.
Then open git bash and run these commands:

```
$ cd /your/current/project/path/
$ git checkout v1.9.3
$ git branch develop
$ git checkout develop
```

Now make your change on project and then:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "v1.9.4"
```

Your changes stored in develop branch.
If you want to change master branch to v1.9.4:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge develop
```

And now you can update github like before.
I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really make sense to me. Seems like you need to develop your code off of the 1.10 version so you can ensure that you are compatible with that. You could copy your current changes to a branch off of the 1.10 version and build there and try that. If you are saying that you only want one branch of your code, well you can build it off the later version and try it with the new version, but it seems likely that things will go awry due to the version skew - its hard to say since there isn't enough info presented here. My first idea is just to keep two branches, one for each baseline that you are developing for, and come up with a scheme to move commits from one branch to the other, as you develop. You might have a submodule for your code as well.

Comment: When I make a branch with GitHub desktop, it doens'nt make a second folder where my other branch for 1.10 is.